# positive lookbehind multiple times

Tags: python, regex

```
"Name":"abc"
```

Expected output: Name

Here in this case, when I have the value "abc", I need to fetch the word Name by using positive look behind and extracting the words between the occurences of ".

Comment: Which Regex flavor are you using?

Comment: Why does it have to look behind multiple times?

Comment: You do not need any lookbehind. Just capture 1 or more chars other than `"` in between `"` that precede `:"abc"`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything fancy like look-behinds for this functionality:

```
"([A-Za-z]*)":"abc"
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JG3cer/1)

**Edit**: Since you've added the `python` tag, escape your quotes:

```
\"([A-Za-z]*)\":\"abc\"
```

[New Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JG3cer/2/)